# Help with solving a limit

Tags: limits

I have a limit which comes from some calculations that I was doing in quantum mechanics, but I can't solve it on my own.

So what I have is
\begin{equation}
L = \lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}f(a)} \exp\left({-\frac{(x-b)^2}{2f(a)} } + \frac{i}{a} x c\right)
\end{equation}

$x, b, c, a$ and $f(a)$ are all real. I think I'm most interested in something like $f(a) \in O(\sqrt{x})$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ (although I often make a mess of the O notation, by that I meant as fast as or faster than square root x), but I'd be interested in behaviour that went as $O(x^a)$ for $a \in (0,1/2)$ too.
And it would be lovely if it was equal to $\delta(x-b)$, but I'm aware that mathematics doesn't work that way!

My first attempt was just to do something like this

\begin{equation}
L = \delta(x - b) \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\exp\left(\frac{i}{a} x c\right)
\end{equation}
Which to me looks reasonably horrible, but maybe a friendly mathematician will tell me something like that the phase oscillates so fast that I can ignore it, and all my problems will be solved? (ha ha ha...)

So anyway my second (presumably more realistic) attempt was to complete the square
\begin{equation}
L = \lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}f(a)} \exp\left({-\frac{(x-(b + i\frac{c f(a)}{a}))^2}{2f(a)} } + \frac{(b + i\frac{c f(a)}{a})^2-b^2}{2f(a)}\right)
\end{equation}

And then using my mystical powers of guessing what I think limits should work out to be like, I feel like this would be equal to $\delta(x-b)$ provided that

\begin{equation}M = \lim_{a\rightarrow0} \frac{(b + i\frac{c f(a)}{a})^2-b^2}{2f(a)} = 0\end{equation}

So I drag back out out my L'Hôpital's rule that was lurking around in a first year mathematics course somewhere to produce

\begin{equation}M = i c \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1}{a} - \frac{f(a)}{f'(a)}\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\left(b+i\frac{c f(a)}{a}\right
)\end{equation}

And then this is only equal to zero if $f(a) = a$?
I was hoping for a wider range of possible cases really

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Note that your last expression equals zero if $f(a)/f'(a)=a$, not when $f(a)=a$.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, not sure how I missed that. That still only gives me $f(a) = k a$ though, I was hoping for something less restrictive...